# How to define a C++ class destructor with Cython?

Tags: c++, cython, destructor

```
cdef cppclass ObjectDef:
    string* name_ptr

    ObjectDef():
        this.name_ptr = new string(b"John")
    ~ObjectDef(string _name):    # <= cython error on "~"
        del this.name_ptr

cdef ObjectDef* my_obj_ptr = new ObjectDef()
del my_obj_ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

You would define a `__dealloc__` in this case

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name_ptr = new string(b"John")

def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.name_ptr
```